# Windows 8 Pro Tablet Com Ports

Tags: windows, windows-8, serial-port

We have recently purchased a Windows 8 Pro Tablet for development. However some of our applications interface to a GSM or 3G modem by the COM port.

However in from looking in device manager it seems that Windows 8 doesn't list the COM ports?

Is there a new way to interface to COM ports?

Comment: Are you talking about Microsoft's new Surface Pro? It doesn't have any serial ports, which is why Windows won't find them. You'll need to add a USB/Serial adapter.

Comment: It's a Lenovo ThinkPad 2 with Windows 8 Pro. Normally you are able to send AT commands to a COM port.

I've read that Windows 8 now has a Mobile Broadband API instead, but this quite restrictive.

I'm thinking that it might be best to go down the Gobi route to interface to the modem?

Comment: There are many parts of the API that aren't available in RT mode, but classic applications should be able to access the full classic API. I'll have to defer to someone with more specific knowledge of Windows 8.